# Facebook js APi, fetching photos without permissions returns empty array instead of error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get a user's photos via Facebook's JS API ('/me/photos' and '/me/photos/uploaded').
If I have he user_photos permissions it all works well, but when I don't I just get an empty array back instead of an error (which makes it a bit hard to distinguish between user's with no photos, and missing permissions).

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0 is seems like an error should be returned.

Am I missing something?

Thanks
Yaron

Comment: There will always be an empty array in return in this case.

Comment: So I need to query for permissions before I make this call? Kind of strange, and doesn't fit with what FB says in its docs.